# Error while freeing memory in C after program giving correct answer

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, calloc

So here's the code for primes sieve, and it gives correct output, does exactly what I want it to do, except ugly errors after printing correct result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

void prime_gen(int *, int);
void show_primes(unsigned long, unsigned long, int *, int);

int main(void)
{
  int no_testcases=0;
  int count=0;
  unsigned long lower=0,upper=0;
  unsigned long size;

  size=sqrt(1000000000);
  printf("%lu\n", size);
  int * primes, *primes_temp;;
  primes=(int *)calloc(size+1,sizeof(int));
  assert (primes!=NULL);

  prime_gen(primes, size+1); /* generates array of 0 and 1's indicating if index is a prime number */

  scanf("%d", &no_testcases); /* no of test cases */
  while (count<no_testcases)
  {
    scanf("%lu %lu", &lower, &upper);
    show_primes(lower, upper, primes, size+1); /* shows all prime numbers in given range */
    count++;
    if (count!=no_testcases)
      putchar('\n');
  }

  free(primes);

  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
31622
size=31623, set_index=63248, index=31625
1
1
10  
2
3
5
7
No of primes = 4
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (out): 0x09d49008 ***
a.out: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Przerwane (core dumped)
```

Here's code for primes generator and show_primes:

```
void prime_gen(int * tab, int size) /* 0== is prime, 1== is not prime */
{
  tab[0]=1;
  tab[1]=1;
  unsigned long index=2;
  unsigned long set_index;


  for(index=2;index<=size;index++)
  {
    while (index<=size && tab[index]!=0) /* goes to next prime number */
    {
      index++;
    }
    for(set_index=index+index;set_index<=size;set_index+=index)
      tab[set_index]=1;
  }
  printf("size=%d, set_index=%lu, index=%lu\n", size, set_index, index);
}

void show_primes(unsigned long l, unsigned long u, int * array, int size)
{
  int index = 0;
  int is_prime=1;
  int primes_count=0;

  for(l;l<=u;l++)
  {
    if (l<=size) /* if l is valid index of array with primes */
    {
      if(array[l]==0)
      {
    printf("%lu\n", l);
    primes_count++;

      }
    }
    else /* if checked number is bigger than last index of array */
    {
      is_prime=1;
      for (index=2;index<=size;index++)
      {
    if (array[index]==0)
    {
      if (l%index==0)
      {
        is_prime=0;
        break;
      }
    }
      }
      if (is_prime)
      {
    printf("%lu\n", l);
    primes_count++;

      }
    }

  }
  printf("No of primes = %d\n", primes_count);
}
```

I narrowed it to free(primes) as the problem, because when removed error disappears and program terminated as supposed to. And I know array would be better here, but dynamic arrays are new to me and it's supposed to be my lesson on them.
Many thanks for answers.

Comment: The program will have all its memory free'd when it exits, so the quick solution is to just let it exit. ;)  Question: Are you compiling with any optimizations or weird settings?

Comment: are you sure your are not freeing  primes within show_primes function? Can you also put that code?

Comment: no, standard gcc compilation.

Comment: Show definitions of `prime_gen` and `show_primes`.

Comment: functions definitions added.

Comment: @zubergu and input values to reproduce the issue

Comment: @ouah I think for any input so it can be 1 1 10.

Comment: You are indexing past the array with size input as "size+1" and indexing all the was to <=size.  That's definitely a problem.

Comment: @Jim That's it. Changing arguments from (size+1) to (size) fixed the code.

Comment: @zubergu  Cool.  Glad you got your code working.

Comment: @Jim still, shame on me for such a stupid mistake, even for a beginner.

Comment: @zubergu  Happens all the time.  definitely in the top 10 of C errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

```
void prime_gen(int *, int);
void show_primes(unsigned long, unsigned long, int *, int);

int main(void)
{
  int no_testcases=0;
  int count=0;
  unsigned long lower=0,upper=0;
  unsigned long size;

  size=sqrt(1000000000);
  printf("%lu\n", size);
  int * primes, *primes_temp; *primes_head;
  primes=(int *)calloc(size+1,sizeof(int));
  primes_head = primes;
  assert (primes!=NULL);

  /* NOTE CHANGE BELOW */
  prime_gen(primes, size); /* generates array of 0 and 1's indicating if index is a prime number */

  scanf("%d", &no_testcases); /* no of test cases */
  while (count<no_testcases)
  {
    scanf("%lu %lu", &lower, &upper);
    /* NOTE CHANGE HERE */
    show_primes(lower, upper, primes, size); /* shows all prime numbers in given range */
    count++;
    if (count!=no_testcases)
      putchar('\n');
  }

  free(primes_head);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear without more information.  Maybe show_primes is changing the primes ptr....

Comment: as you can see, *primes_temp is a leftover of me trying to do the same. Without success.

Comment: The you are under/overwriting primes with your code.  It works, but the pointer is corrupted.

Comment: Prime_gen(primes, size) NOT size+1

Answer (score 1):

In `prime_gen` function, you have this:

```
for(set_index=index+index;set_index<=size;set_index+=index)
  tab[set_index]=1;
```

You are overflowing your array. On the last iteration you write to element `tab[set_index]` with `set_index` value greater than `size`.

Try to change your `for` loop stop condition to: `set_index < size`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `primes_gen` and `show_primes` with the `primes` array and the size of the array. Inside those functions, you are reading from and writing to one past the bounds of the array:

```
for(set_index=index+index;set_index<=size;set_index+=index)
  tab[set_index] = 1;
```

This is corrupting your array and so your call to `free()` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

try moving `scanf("%lu %lu", &lower, &upper);` outside of the loop